# delete numeric numbers in all columns python

Tags: python, pandas

I want delete all numeric number in columns ,

Exemple :

1. ABC *12547 NDFRE12   -> ABC * NDFRE
2. 12aRE 15P            -> aRE P

I want a code with python. I talk about all columns and not only one row.

Using Excel file .xlsx

Column A for example

Answer (score 2):

Try this for entire dataframe:

```
df = df.replace(to_replace=r'\d+', value='', regex=True)
```

For only one column:

```
df['COLUMN'] = df['COLUMN'].str.replace('\d+', '')
```

Comment: Wasif Hasan , Thanks ! it's exactly what I want !

Comment: If it works for you then please accept it as answer by clicking the big check mark and upvote with the ^ looking button

Comment: if I want delete too (*PO, *INV, * )  I need whrite new line ?

Comment: Then replace with a newline (`\n`) instead

Comment: df['COLUMN'] = df['COLUMN'].str.replace('\*INV', '')   ? I can white all in same line ?

Comment: What do you mean by "white"

Comment: like df['COLUMN'] = df['COLUMN'].str.replace('\*INV ; \*PO';\*, '')

Comment: No try `df['COLUMN'] = df['COLUMN'].str.replace('*INV ; *PO', '')` instead

Comment: df['COLUMN'] = df['COLUMN'].str.replace('*INV ; *PO', '')   does't work.   raise source.error(''nothing to repeat",

Comment: sorry no white but :  write

Answer (score 1):

Try with `replace`

```
l=['ABC *12547 NDFRE12',
'12aRE 15P -> aRE P']
s = pd.Series(l)
0    ABC *12547 NDFRE12
1    12aRE 15P -> aRE P
s = s.str.replace('\d+','')
0       ABC * NDFRE
1    aRE P -> aRE P
dtype: object
```